# What is the most efficient single-photon detector to date?

Tags: photons, quantum-optics, experimental-technology

(This question depends on the current time period, so the reader should make note and be aware of the date of the posted answers.)

I am wondering what is the most efficient state-of-the-art single-photon detector we have currently achieved. There are two things we want to suppress:

- False negatives: a detection does not go off when the photon strikes a screen.
- False positives: a detection goes off when it shouldn't have due to thermal noise or cosmic particles.

What is the best technology we have that suppresses both of the above simultaneously? Is there any technology that achieves a 90% efficiency or more or is that still a long way off?

The wavelength/energy range for the detector can be any range to make the question easier.

Comment: What's the expected energy of the photon?

Comment: @Loong For generosity, any energy range would be acceptable.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to tell the difference between a photon coming from blackbody radiation of some nearby object from a photon coming from whatever source you really want to study. So even if you eliminate false positives from thermal noise in your electronics and cosmic particles (outside the EM band you're studying), you'll still have false positives from thermal radiation to deal with.

Comment: Of course you can surround your detector with a cold shield to minimize the background radiation, but you can't totally eliminate it.

Comment: For photons with a wavelength of about 560 nm (yellow-green), some CMOS sensors, which are the type used in cell phones, have a quantum efficiency of about 95%. But if you really want to quantify sensitivity to single photons, it seems technical and there is probably no simple answer. There are various types of noise and bias.

Answer (score 4):

Quantum efficiencies of higher than 90 % are no problem in regions of the spectrum.

- Photomultiplier tubes (with scintillators)
- Solid state detectors

Here is a comparison for the visible: https://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/tb/supplements/pit/briefs/29910

Or this new design: https://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/tb/supplements/pit/briefs/30087

Answer (score 1):

[Superconducting nanowire single photon detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_nanowire_single-photon_detector) and [transition-edge sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition-edge_sensor)  ([>95% end-to-end measured at 1550nm](http://kiss.caltech.edu/workshops/photon/presentations/nam.pdf)) Both operate near a phase transition superconductor - normal metal, where absorption of a photon changes the resistance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer?